# Symfony comparing two entities and getting names of different fields

Tags: php, symfony, object, entity, difference

Is there an easy way of comparing two entities and getting the names of the fields which do not match without using an if statement for each of the them?

Comment: Which `ORM` are you using?

Comment: If you're using `Doctrine` you can turn you two entities to be compared into arrays and then compare them. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#example-1--simple-entity-with-no-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

$array_diff = array_keys(    
    array_diff_key(
        get_object_vars($foo),
        get_object_vars($bar)
));
```

`$array_diff` will be an array containing every property of `$foo` that is not found in `$bar`.

I'm from my smartphone so I didn't tested it